# Java - Parse a Date String to a Date with Specific Date Format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a date string "Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 ICT 2015". I tried to use SimpleDateFormat to convert this string to a date with format "YYYY-mm-DD". The code looks like this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-mm-DD").parse("Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 ICT 2015");
```

But I got an exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 ICT 2015"
```

Comment: No, you have to `parse` your `String` using the format that it's in; then `format` your `Date` using the format that you want it to be in.  Also better to use the Java 8 classes than the pre-Java 8 ones.

Comment: How does `Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 ICT 2015` match `YYYY-mm-DD`?  The pattern and the input need to match before it will have any chance of parsing it.  Having said that, you should be using the newer `java.time` API instead

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem you mean I have to parse my date string"Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 ICT 2015" to a Date?

Comment: Yes. The `parse` method converts a String to a Date. The `format` method converts a Date to a String. You'll need both.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Also if there’s a way you can, don’t rely on parsing `ICT` as a time zone. While this particular abbreviation *may* only mean Indochina Time, the most commonly used three to five letter abbreviations are ambiguous, so the risk of getting an incorrect time is great.

Answer (score 3):

Most programming languages have a concept of "date/time" representation, which represents some point in time and allows the application of rules, such as time zones and leap years/seconds and other oddities to be applied.

When parsing a `String` value, you must know the format that the `String` is in, let's face it, what does `3/3/3` mean?

Java 8 replaced the existing `Date`/`Calendar` API which a much richer and less error prone API and you should make use of it as much as possible.

The first step is to construct a `DateTimeFormatter` of which represents the desired input format

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

See [the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more details on the specifiers.

Next, you want to parse the text using the formatter...

```
String text = "Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 ICT 2015";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
System.out.println(zdt);
```

*nb: I've used a `ZonedDateTime` because I want to carry over the time zone information, you could use a `LocalDateTime`, but that would depend on your underlying needs*

This will print `2015-12-02T00:00+07:00[Asia/Bangkok]`

> I expect that the date will have "YYYY-mm-DD" format

An important concept to get your head around is, the `toString` value of the a date object has nothing to do with its underlying representation and only represents a human readable representation of the object.

To format the date value into something else, you need to use another `DateTimeFormatter`...

```
String formattedDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(zdt);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

And the will print `2015-12-02`

Comment: you are right, I have an incorrect understanding about the usage of `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 1):

Does this serves your purpose:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse("Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 ICT 2015");

//convert this date to the desired format
 DateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 System.out.println(target.format(date));
```

Comment: I expect that the date will have "YYYY-mm-DD" format not "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" format.

Comment: @MenX That's not how parsing works - it returns an instance of `Date`, which a representation of a the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. You will need to use a different formatter to format the `Date` instance into a `String` of the desired format

Comment: I extended the code sample, to further format it

Comment: While this works in some cases (not always), using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` is strongly discouraged.